# Rewriting logarithms

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, logarithms, computer-science, discrete-logarithms

I am trying to understand the lower bound of a Bloom filter and want to know how this rewriting is possible from [this](https://www.eecs.harvard.edu/%7Emichaelm/postscripts/im2005b.pdf) article (page 6-7 (or 490)).

If $$m\geq n\mathrm{log}_2(1/\epsilon)$$ is some minumum size of a bitvector and we have $f$ as a false positive rate with $m$ as a power: $$f=(1/2)^{m\ln/2}$$ How does $m$ becomes (after plugging it into $f$): $$m\geq n\frac{\log_2(1/\epsilon)}{\ln2}=n\log_2e\cdot\log_2(1/\epsilon)$$And what does it mean when $m$ is within a factor of $\log_2e \approx1.44$ of the asymptotic lower bound assuming that the right hand side of the last equation above is the lower bound?

Comment: If $A, B>0$ then $\log_BA=1/\log_AB.$ In particular $\log_2e=1/\log_e 2=1/\ln 2.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The asymptopic lower bound for $m$ is $n \log_2(1/\epsilon)$. That is the amount required number of bits required to represent all sets of $n$ elements allowing false positives for at most a fraction of $\epsilon$.

Now, the expected false positive rate is $f=(1/2)^k \ge (1/2)^{m \ln 2/ n}$. To achieve $f \le \epsilon$. We need

$$(1/2)^{m \ln 2/n} \le \epsilon$$

Taking reciprocal,

$$2^{m \ln 2/n} \ge \frac1\epsilon$$

Taking log with base $2$,
$$m \ln 2/n \ge \log_2(1/\epsilon)$$

$$m  \ge \frac{n}{\ln 2}\log_2(1/\epsilon)$$

Now $\ln 2=\frac{\log_2 2}{\log_2 e}=\frac1{\log_2 e}$,

Hence we requires $$ m \ge n \log_2 e \log_2(1/\epsilon).$$

The asymptotic lower bound was $n\log_2(\frac1/\epsilon)$.

Now, for space-wise Bloom filters, it is $\log_2 e$ times that.

Comment: Thank you. Much appreciated. So in your last step, do I then substitute $m$ with the lower bound so: $m\geq n\log_2{e}\log_2{1/\epsilon} => n\log_2{1/\epsilon}\geq n\log_2{e}\log_2{1/\epsilon} => 1\geq \log_2{e}$ ??

Comment: Let $g \le f$, that is $g$ is a lowerbound of $f$, if we want $f \le \epsilon$, then we definitely need $g \le \epsilon$. Here $g = (1/2)^{m \ln 2 n}$. From there we manipulate and solve for inequalities involving $m$. it is not just a substitution.  I can't following your reasoning in your comment,  I don't think $1 \ge \log_2 e$ is true.

Comment: I get it now. $m$ is only $\log_2{e}$ away from the optimised space. Thanks.

Comment: Can you take a look at this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4219732/rewriting-an-equation-in-the-terms-of-algorithmic-complexity